# efficient way to select odd rows and specific cell within a table using css

Tags: html, css

I have following example table:

```
<table id="inputTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mike</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>eric</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>jonas</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I was wondering how may I be able to select every odd row and 2nd cell within the table?

I came up with this:

```
#inputTable tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(2){
    background-color: red;
}
```

but it didn't work. Anyone has any solution?

Comment: Maybe because the id specified on the table is inputTable while in the CSS you have used #mainTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS did not work because it targets `#mainTable` but your HTML says `id="inputTable"`.

Comment: apologies forgot to change the id name while editing here, its not the case

Comment: yeah.. i dont no what went wrong there.. tested on another html file it worked. might have the references.. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(2){
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="inputTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mike</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>eric</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>jonas</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to something like this for odd even selection using css.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```